# Vim indentation for [{ }] in javascript

Tags: javascript, vim

I expect this:

```
var x = [      
    {  
    }  
]
```

This is happening:

```
var x = [  
{  
}  
]
```

{ and } should be indented right.

I have tried:
`expandtab`
`tabstop`
`shiftwidth`

But nothing. I don't want to use any other indent script out there.
Happy with default but any setting to correct such indentation would
make my day.

I am using Vim 7.4 installed using source on Debian 8.

Comment: The default Vim Javascript indent file uses the `cindent` rules, which are built-in. I'm not aware of any way of configuring them, short of reimplementing the whole thing in your own script with `indentexpr`. Maybe ask on [vi.stackexchange.com](http://vi.stackexchange.com/)?

Comment: I am reading about indentexpr. But reimplementing is like creating indent script of my own.

Comment: How about `set autoindent, set smartindent`?

Comment: No. Tried already. They don't solve the issue.